# In gradle how do you create separate test reports for separate tasks?

Tags: java, junit, gradle, continuous-integration, acceptance-testing

I have three test source sets

```
/src/tests/...
src/test-integration/
src/test-acceptance/
```

`gradle build` only runs the unit tests while I have separate tasks for running test-integration and test-acceptance. [This setup](http://blog.diabol.se/?cat=47), basically:

```
task acceptanceTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Runs acceptance tests"
    testReportDirName ="acceptance"
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.acceptanceTest.output.classesDir
    classpath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.acceptanceTest.runtimeClasspath
    useJUnit()
    testLogging {
      events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

Now my only problem is that I'd like acceptance/integration tests to print their reports somewhere other than "test" folder, since they over-write one another. Basically I'd like to change the `testReportDirName` property but only for a task.

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: Version 2.0, from the ppa

Comment: It seems that it's possible to change the dire where test report is generated in gradle v. `2.1`. Navigate to `$GRADLE_HOME/samples/testing/testReport` and there You can find example how it can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the default test results and reports directories as such:

```
task acceptanceTest(type: Test) {
    reports.html.destination = file("$reports.html.destination/acceptance")
    reports.junitXml.destination = file("$reports.junitXml.destination/acceptance")
}
```